# Overall rank of other ranks

Tags: statistics

I've searched on Google and this forum, but haven't find what I really wanted.

I have X items (say 10), which are ranked by 3 different criteria (say "Fastest", "Lightest" and "Best value for money"). They are ranked from 1 to X, where 1 is the best and X is the last position.
Each criterion has a weight (say Fastest = 5, Lightest = 7 and Best value = 8).
Something like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98VPj.jpg)

Now I have to generate an overall rank for those items, based on their ranks on those 3 criteria and also on the weight of each criterion.

My solution so far would be a weighted arithmetic mean, but instead of multiplying the rank and the weight, I divided the rank by the weight. So, considering the example on the picture, for the 1st item it would be:

1*(1/5) + 1*(1/7) + 3*(1/8) divided by (1/5) + (1/7) + (1/8)

And then rank the result for each item again.
Does that have any sense?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you simply compute $W=Fastest*2+Lightest*1+BestValue*3$ and rank them with this new value ? (i.e. sort by $W$)

Comment: The smallest value being the best? It could be. That's exactly the problem. I'm not sure how to create a rank of ranks, where 1 is "the best".

Comment: Is each of the three characteristics 'fastest', 'lightest', and 'best value' of equal importance? The same task is faced by magazines that seek to rank US cities as to overall quality of life by merging weather, cost of living, cultural amenities, health care, and so on. Rankings can be very different depending on which characteristics are most valued. Some magazines give clues as to how they do this.

Comment: No, actually each one has a weight: 5, 7 and 8.